# How to change tiles colour on hover and revert to default on mouse out without affecting text colour?

Tags: jquery, css

I need some help regarding the following tutorial
http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/07/12/animated-text-and-icon-menu/

So my question is - How to change tiles background colour on hover and revert to default on mouse out without affecting text colour?

I've tried to get in touch with this tutorials author but didn't get any answer.
Could someone help pls?

Thanks

Comment: make the `data-hovercolor` (now they're different on every element - that's why the color changing) on `<li>-s` match the `.sti-menu li a h2` color

Answer (score 1):

Instead replacing this with the original color:

```
<ul id="sti-menu" class="sti-menu">
    <li data-hovercolor="#37c5e9">
[...]
```

I would suggest if you don't need the functionality simply delete the data-hovercolor from all LI elements and then from the script remove the part that applies them. Modified version:

```
$menuItems.bind('mouseenter', function(e) {

    clearTimeout(t_mouseenter);

    var $item       = $(this),
        $wrapper    = $item.children('a'),
        wrapper_h   = $wrapper.height(),
        // the elements that animate inside this menu item
        $movingItems= $wrapper.find('.sti-item');

    t_mouseenter    = setTimeout(function() {
        // indicates the item is on hover state
        $item.addClass('sti-current');

        $movingItems.each(function(i) {
            var $item           = $(this),
                item_sti_type   = $item.data('type'),
                speed           = settings.animMouseenter[item_sti_type].speed,
                easing          = settings.animMouseenter[item_sti_type].easing,
                delay           = settings.animMouseenter[item_sti_type].delay,
                dir             = settings.animMouseenter[item_sti_type].dir,
                // if dir is 1 the item moves downwards
                // if -1 then upwards
                style           = {'top' : -dir * wrapper_h + 'px'};

            if( item_sti_type === 'icon' ) {
                // this sets another bg image position for the icon
                style.backgroundPosition    = 'bottom left';
            } 
            // we hide the icon, move it up or down, and then show it
            $item.hide().css(style).show();
            clearTimeout($item.data('time_anim'));
            $item.data('time_anim',
                setTimeout(function() {
                    // now animate each item to its default tops
                    // each item will animate with a delay specified 
                    // in the options
                    $item.stop(true)
                         .animate({top : $item.data('deftop') + 'px'}, speed, easing);
                }, delay)
            );
        });
        // animate the bg color of the item
        $wrapper.stop(true).animate({
            backgroundColor: settings.defaultTextColor
        }, settings.boxAnimSpeed );

    }, 100);    

})
```

WARNING: haven't tested it, simply removed lines 11 and the else block at line 31 from the original snippet - those are the only lines that get and set the hover text color as far as I can tell.

Comment: Great it worked thanks! But imagine I want the background black and text white on mousehover and background white and text black on mouse out. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

It's simple, doit with css.

CSS

```
.sti-item span{
    color:#000;
}
```

HTML

```
<li data-hovercolor="#37c5e9">
    <a href="#">
        <h2 data-type="mText" class="sti-item"><span>Advanced Patient Care</span></h2>
        <h3 data-type="sText" class="sti-item"><span>Personalized to your needs</span></h3>
        <span data-type="icon" class="sti-icon sti-icon-care sti-item"></span>
    </a>
</li>
```

Or remove mText & sText text color references in the JS.

Comment: Great it worked thanks! But imagine I want the background black and text white on mousehover and background white and text black on mouse out. How can I achieve this?

Comment: li:hover .sti-item span{
    color:#fff;
}